# How to achieve soft round effect on border in JavaFX

Tags: css, javafx

I have a generic border of a node and i want to make the border look like this image (both CSS and code way) in JavaFX:

[image: effect]

Can anybody help me?

Thanks in advance

Comment: you want to add the border to a pane? or is that kind of a separator?

Comment: Yeah, exactly. I have a generic node and i want this effect to the bottom border of that node

Answer (score 0):

You should use box-shadow to add a soft round effect with border and border-radius.

```
border: 1px solid #888888;
box-shadow: 1px 1px 2px #888888;
border-radius: 25px;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but i need something similar for javaFX, those are normal CSS rules, i need javaFX css rules and also a way to do it by code (if it's possible). I also edited my question to better understand that this is about javaFX and not standard CSS for web development

Answer (score 0):

**The main Class for stage**

```
public class SpiderMan extends Application {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}

@Override
public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
    FXMLLoader loader = new FXMLLoader(
        getClass().getResource(
            "SpiderMan.fxml"
        )
    );
    loader.setController(new clipRound());

    Pane batman = loader.load();

    stage.setTitle("Where's Spider man Round image?");
    stage.setScene(new Scene(batman));
    stage.show();
}
```

}

**The Round Image Class View**

```
 class clipRound {
    @FXML
    private ImageView imageView;

    @FXML
    public void initialize() {
        // set a clip to apply rounded border to the original image.
        Rectangle clip = new Rectangle(
            imageView.getFitWidth(), imageView.getFitHeight()
        );
        clip.setArcWidth(20); the radius Arch
        clip.setArcHeight(20); the radius Arch
        imageView.setClip(clip);

        // snapshot the rounded image.
        SnapshotParameters parameters = new SnapshotParameters();
        parameters.setFill(Color.TRANSPARENT);
        WritableImage image = imageView.snapshot(parameters, null);

        // remove the rounding clip so that our effect can show through.
        imageView.setClip(null);

        // apply a shadow effect.
        imageView.setEffect(new DropShadow(20, Color.BLACK));

        // store the rounded image in the imageView.
        imageView.setImage(image);
    }
}
```

**The round Image FXML view "SpiderMan.fxml"**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.Image?>
<?import javafx.scene.image.ImageView?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>
<AnchorPane id="AnchorPane" maxHeight="-Infinity" maxWidth="-Infinity" minHeight="-Infinity" minWidth="-Infinity" prefHeight="313.0" prefWidth="477.0" style="-fx-background-color: azure;" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/2.2">
<children>
    <ImageView fx:id="imageView" layoutX="29.0" layoutY="44.0" fitHeight="224.0" fitWidth="400.0" pickOnBounds="true" preserveRatio="true">
      <image>
        <Image url="http://collider.com/wp-content/uploads/lego-batman-movie-dc-super-heroes-unite-1.jpg" />
      </image>
    </ImageView>
  </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

Snapshot :
[snapshot programme is running](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0rWgG.png)

Comment: Sorry but i don't think this answer can help me. Anyway, thanks for the try, i've really appreciated

Comment: Look , you can add javaFX style to the image itself setStyle (border-radius: 25px) but this type of border won't work for images it works for other controls in javaFX like HBox and StackPane so , you can add the image in StackPane then apply what do you want on the stackPane
The above answer is a tricky one to work around the problem that image doesn't accept border style

Comment: I have edited my question again. I hope it could be clear enough now